# WPF: How to Hide a modal dialog box without destroying it? (its DialogResult)

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, hide, dialogresult

I've got a modal dialog box and (when user presses its OK button) I want to hide it, show another modal dialog box (MessageBox for example) and then show it back again. My problem is that when the dialog is hidden, its DialogResult gets `false` and of course its getting closed right after the button's handler method ends. I've even tried to set Opacity to 0 instead of `Hide()` but that doesn't work at all (it's still visible).

Is there a way to hide a modal dialog box for a moment **without** closing it?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround that is working for me:

To prevent the window from being closed once you set the DialogResult, create your own DialogResult instead:

> public new bool DialogResult;

Now you can still set the variable and choose Hide() instead of Close().
So all the places where DialogResult is set I add a

> Hide();

So i looks like this:

```
DialogResult=true;
Hide();
```

or

```
DialogResult=false;
Hide();
```

That way I can do a new ShowDialog() again.

So if I need to reopen the window until the content is correct (if validation happens after closing), it would look something like this:

```
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new MyDialog();
        bool ok = false;
        while (!ok)
        {
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialog.DialogResult)
            {
                ok = DoSomeValidation();
            }
            else
            {
                ok = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not deal with the result but see how to return data from a Page
PageModal is a Page
You use NavigationWindow for the modal part

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PageModal pageModal = new PageModal();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLaunchModal(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationWindow navWindow = new NavigationWindow();
        navWindow.Content = pageModal;
        navWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: So... You're just saying that there is NO way to hide a modal window and bring it back in WPF... and you suggest me to REPLACE its content instead of hiding it? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the opacity IS working. I just had it blocked by finished animation (with HoldEnd behavior) and I didn't knew about it. So, if anyone has the same problem and needs to hide a modal window, the `Opacity = 0;` is the solution.